# Qt - What do we mean by those code snippets

Tags: c++, qt, this

I just have those questions about those code sinppets from the `C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4` book:

```
GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
```

Does that mean we are *inheriting* `QDialog(parent)`? Or, what exactly does this mean?

```
setupUi(this);
```

Here, this code snippet is part of the `gotocelldialog.cpp` file, which is the implementation of `gotocelldialog.h` header file. What do we mean by `this` in this context? What are we trying to setup? And, what kind of setup will that be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
```

`:` signifies an initializer list. And it meant, `parent` is being passed as a parameter to `QDialog` constructor. I assume `GoToCellDialog` is derived from `QDialog` and so sending `parent` to it's constructor. So, before even body of `GoToCellDialog` is executed, `QDialog` constructor is executed.

This example should give you an idea -

```
class foo
{
    int number ;
    public:
        foo(int i) : number(i) // Means copying value of i to number
        {}
};

class bar : public foo
{
    public:
        bar(int temp) : foo(temp)
        { // <- Before getting here, foo sub object must be constructed.
          //  Because the order of construction takes from parent to child.
        }
};
```

In the above example, definitely an argument for `foo` constructor must be passed while instantiation of `bar`. So, initializer list is the only way because there is no default constructor( i.e., constructor with no arguments) available for `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, is `QDialog(parent)` now the value of `*parent` in `GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent)` or vice versa? Thanks
`

Comment: @user - I didn't understand you. While instantiating `GoToCellDialog` what ever you passed as the argument will get passed to `QWidget` constructor first.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> Does that mean we are inheriting QDialog(parent)?

Yes, this is basic C++ inheritance.

> `setupUi(this);`

In short: The 'User Interface compiler' ([uic](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/uic.html)) compiles/translates the xml file to C++ code which will be compiled and linked. The setupUi() function ensures that the Qt designer widgets you made (generated C++ code) are setup to be used by your code by [Building the Widget tree](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, what does `this` here refere to?

Comment: It's a reference to the current object/class. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_science))